# How do I write to the application window log with MVC

Tags: model-view-controller

I have a simple MVC application that sometimes fails in production. I would like to write a message to the log that I can view with server manager. It seems like a simple thing to do but I've not found any reference to others doing it.

Can someone please help. I'm stuck "-(

Marie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w20x90k.aspx

```
System.Diagnostices.Eventlog.WriteEntry("Application", "your message here");
```